# “Most intuitive” average of $P$ for all $x\in A \cap [a,b]$, where $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, intuition, average

Consider $P:A\to\mathbb{R}$ where $P(x)> 0 \text{,} \ $ $A$ is an  subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and

$$P(x)= \begin{cases}
P_1(x) & x \in A_1\\
P_2(x) & x \in A_2\\
\end{cases}$$

where $A=A_1\cup A_2$ and $A_1,A_2$ are pairwise disjoint.

What is the "most intuitive" average of $P(x)$, for all $x \in A\cap[a,b]$, that is unique and where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$?

Note “unique” means a system that produces a single average, instead of multiple averages, using reasoning/intuition.

Also note this question is subjective but there are areas of math (such as measure theory) that is  based on intuitions/ intuitive properties. For example, we can pick any arbitrary measure to find the average of Dirichlet's Function in $[0,1]$, but instead, we use the Lebesgue measure.

Why is the Lebesgue measure intuitive? Because if real numbers in $[a,b]$ are written as infinite, randomly generated digits; there is zero probability they will represent a number in $[a,b]$. Moreover, there is zero probability that finite, randomly generated digits will repeat infinitely to give rational numbers; hence, these digits have a probability $1$ of being irrational.  Say we multiplied these intuitive probabilities times $b-a$. This gives the results of the Lebesgue measure. Hence we can state the Lebesgue measure is intuitive for these cases?

However, if we are focusing on countable $A\cap[a,b]$, it should still have a measure of one and the average of $P$ should exist between the infimum and supermum of its range. The problem is most countably additive measures of $A\cap[a,b]$ is zero giving $P$ an average outside the range.

What measure should we use instead? What do you think are intuitive properties/examples that the average should follow?

Here are two examples, I believe our measure and average should match

---

If $A$ has a Lebesgue measure of one the average of $P$ should intuitively be

$$\int_{\mu(A_1\cap[a,b])}P_1(x)dx+\int_{\mu(A_2\cap[a,b])}P_2(x)dx$$

Where $\mu$ is a measure that equals the Lebesgue measure (when the Lebesgue measure of $A$ is one).

Even better, we could use the [Gauge Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral), which is far more general and doesn't use a measure. However, even the Gauge integral gives the average of $P$ zero, when defined on a domain with zero Lebesgue measure.

---

Here are two cases that the average of $P$, where the Lebesgue measure of $A\cap[a,b]$ is zero, should intuitively follow.

If $A_1$ and $A_2$ are finite in $[a,b]$, the average of $P$ is

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{i\in A\cap[a,b]}P(i)}{\left|A\cap[a,b]\right|}=\frac{\left|A_1\cap[a,b]\right|\sum\limits_{i_1\in A_1\cap[a,b]}P(i_1)}{\left|A_1\cap[a,b]\right|\left|A\cap[a,b]\right|}+\frac{\left|A_2\cap[a,b]\right|\sum\limits_{i_2\in A_2\cap[a,b]}P(i_2)}{\left|A_2\cap[a,b]\right|\left|A\cap[a,b]\right|}=\frac{\left|A_1\cap[a,b]\right|}{\left|A\cap[a,b]\right|}\sum\limits_{i_1\in A_1\cap[a,b]}P(i_1)\frac{1}{\left|A_1\cap[a,b]\right|}+\frac{\left|A_2\cap[a,b]\right|}{\left|A\cap[a,b]\right|}\sum\limits_{i_2\in A_2\cap[a,b]}P(i_2)\frac{1}{\left|A_2\cap[a,b]\right|}$$

And probability measure $\mu(X\cap[a,b])$ for $X\subseteq A$ is

$$\mathbf{W_1}=\mu(A_1\cap[a,b])=\frac{\left|A_1\cap[a,b]\right|}{\left|A\cap[a,b]\right|}$$

$$\mathbf{W_2}=\mu(A_2\cap[a,b])=\frac{\left|A_2\cap[a,b]\right|}{\left|A\cap[a,b]\right|}$$

$$\mathbf{W}_1\sum\limits_{i_1\in A_1\cap[a,b]}P(i_1)\frac{1}{\left|A_1\cap[a,b]\right|}+\mathbf{W}_2\sum\limits_{i_2\in A_2\cap[a,b]}P(i_2)\frac{1}{\left|A_2\cap[a,b]\right|}$$

---

If $A_1$ is countable infinite in $[a,b]$ and $A_2$ is finite, since $A\cap[a,b]$ is countably infinite, if $\mathbf{J}_m$ contains all finite subsets of $A\cap[a,b]$ where $\max\limits_{m\in\mathbb{N}}|\mathbf{J}_m|=\left|\mathbf{I}_n\right|\le n$; $\mathbf{I}_n$ is arranged as $\left\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\right\}$ where $a\le a_1<a_2<...<a_n\le b$, and

$$ \max_{i\le n,i\in\mathbb{N}}\left(\text{diff} (\mathbf{I_n})\right)=\max_{i\le n,i\in\mathbb{N}}\left\{a_2-a_1,a_3-a_2,...,a_n-a_{n-1}\right\}\le K(n)$$

such that $K:S\to\mathbb{R}$, $\mu(S)=1$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}K(n)=\inf\text{diff}(A)$; then the measures $W_1$ and $W_2$ are

$$\mathbf{W}_{1}=\mathbf{\mu}(A_1\cap[a,b])=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left|A_1\cap \mathbf{I}_n\cap[a,b]\right|}{\left|\mathbf{I}_{n}\cap[a,b]\right|}$$

$$\mathbf{W}_{2}=\mathbf{\mu}(A_2\cap[a,b])=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left|A_2\cap \mathbf{I}_n\cap[a,b]\right|}{\left|\mathbf{I}_{n}\cap[a,b]\right|}$$

And $\text{avg}(P)$ is

$$\mathbf{W}_{1}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i_1\in A_1 \cap I_n \cap [a,b]}P_1(i_1)\frac{1}{\left|A_1\cap I_n\cap[a,b]\right|}+\mathbf{W}_{2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i_2\in A_2 \cap I_n \cap [a,b]}P_2(i_2)\frac{1}{\left|A_2\cap I_n\cap[a,b]\right|}$$

Any $\mathbf{I}_n$ gives the same answer but I'm not sure how to prove this.

Moreover, if $A$ is dense in $[a,b]$,

$$\text{avg}(P)=\frac{1}{b-a}\mathbf{W}_1\int_{a}^{b}P_1(x) \ dx+\frac{1}{b-a}\mathbf{W}_2\int_{a}^{b}P_2(x) \ dx=\frac{1}{b-a}(1)\int_{a}^{b}P_1(x) \ dx+\frac{1}{b-a}(0)\int_{a}^{b}P_2(x) \ dx$$

$$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}P_1(x) \ dx$$

Here's the proof. Since $A$ is dense in $[a,b]$, it can approximate arbitrarily close to any point in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence it's possible for the limits outside the domain to exist. We extend $P:A\to\mathbb{R}$ to $P:A \cup C\to\mathbb{R}$ where for $c\in \mathbb{R}\setminus A$

$$C=\left\{P^{-1}\left(\lim_{\left\{ x\in A\right\}\to c}P(x)\right) \right\}$$

Since $A_1$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, $P:A\cup C\to\mathbb{R}$ can be split into $P_1:A_1\cup C\to\mathbb{R}$ and $P_2:A_2\to\mathbb{R}$.

Since $A_2$ is the discontinuties of $P:A\cup C \to \mathbb{R}$ and the Lebesgue measure of $A_2$ is zero, the Lebesgue criteria for reimman integration states the riemman integral for $P_1:A_1\cup C \to \mathbb{R}$ can exist. Hence we apply the mean value theorem of integration on $P_1$.

---

If $A_1$ and $A_2$ is dense in $[a,b]$ the average is unclear. For one, we could set $\mathbf{I}_n$ to equal subsets of $A_1$, $A_2$ or $A_1\cup A_2$. In this case, $\mathbf{W}_1$ or $\mathbf{W}_2$ could equal anything

I will post my intuition for this example. If you have a measure that matches these intuitions, post it below.

Comment: This leaves us with the sequence that seperate the divisor two. 

$$F_n \cap [a,b]=\left\{\frac{p}{2^k(2q+1)}:p,q\in\mathbb{Z}, k\in\mathbb{N},a<\frac{p}{2^k(2q+1)}<b,2^k\le n, 2q+1 \le n\right\}\bigcup \left\{\frac{jp}{2^k(2q+1)}:p,q\in\mathbb{Z}, k\in\mathbb{N},a<\frac{jp}{2^k(2q+1)}<b,2^k\le n, 2q+1 \le n\right\}$$

It is important to note any $h\in\mathbb{R}$ can be written as $jt$ such that $j\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and $t\in\mathbb{Q}$. The hard part is turning any countable set into a Folner Sequence.

Comment: Is this reasonable? If not could we find the most "intuitive" Folner Sequence of any countable set in the form

Comment: Wait, so, we need to specify a group action to talk about a Følner sequence on $A$, right? Which action are you using?

Comment: This question is really long and complicated so I only read the first part. You could clarify some things since the introduction is not totally clear. For one thing, $A$ is a countable subset of $\mathbb R$, right? And the cases should be $x\in A_1$ and $x\in A_2$ instead of $x=A_1$ and $x=A_2$. Finally, you could clarify that you want to define an average of $P(x)$ over all $x\in A\cup[a,b]$ -- at least, without realizing (from reading further in the question) that $A\subset\mathbb R$, I could only make sense of it as the average of all images $P(x)\in[a,b]$.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Left group action.

Comment: @Rahul Made some edits.

Comment: of what group?${}$

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I assume we are taking the left group action of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$. Does this make sense? I’m not sure, I’m a first year (technically third year) undergraduate.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber It could be $\left(\mathbb{Z},+ \right)$ or $\left(\mathbb{Z},\times \right)$, I’m not sure.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Nevermind, let us start with an example. If I want the Folner Sequence of $\mathbb{Q}$ to be $\left\{\frac{p}{2^{k}(2q+1)}:p,q\in\mathbb{Z}, k\in\mathbb{N},2^{k} \le n, 2q+1 \le n \right\}$ what action must we use?

Comment: wouldn't you just use Cesaro sums? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cesàro_summation)

Comment: @ZacharyHunter We have enumerate any countable set into a sequence of elements? How do we do that? And if there are multiple sequences to enumerate a countable set which one is most intuitive? It would be pointless to say there is no average, between countable $A_1$ and $A_2$, both dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I mean bijecting countable sets to the real numbers is achievable by their very definition. however I guess if you have infinite 1's and 2's, you can arrange them in such a way that you can get any average within the range [1,2]... I guess perhaps you would want to take an average of all "dense limit points" $x$ of $A$, where for any finite subset $S$, $x$ is still a limit point of $A \setminus S$.

Comment: if the set of dense limit points is finite, you'e done. if there's more than countably infinite of them, take an integral, else, rinse and repeat.

Comment: @ZacharyHunter I’m not taking the average of dense limit points. If $A$ is countably dense in $\mathbb{R}$  the output of $P(x)$ is $P_1(x)$ or $P_2(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. The result wouldn’t be a function anymore. We need a different approach.

Comment: @ZacharyHunter If the average could be anything in the range then we should note that. However, could we narrow this down to “fewer averages”.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Why is my post unclear?

Comment: @verret Why is my post unclear

Comment: @GEdgar Why is my post unclear?

Comment: @Shaun Why is my post unclear?

Comment: It's changed since I voted to close it as unclear. At the time I voted, it was a huge post that didn't have a clear question in it, at least at a cursory glance.

Comment: @Shaun Could you reopen it?

Comment: If we had no intuition at all about the probability of repeating decimals, the irrationals would still have full Lebesgue measure, because we could prove it from the definitions.

Comment: I voted to reopen, although *What is the "most intuitive" average* is unclear to me. I've removed the cryptic group-theoretic tags and included the [tag:intuition] tag. I'm  not keen on reopening it to be honest, even now.

Comment: @GerryMyerson If it’s intuitive a singularity and the rationals should have a measure of zero, and the irrationals should have a measure of one, then we can create a measure that meets these requirements. The lebesgue measure works for all these cases. However when we add the intuition that the average, using a measure, should be in the range of the function, then the Lebesgue measure does not work when the domain has a Lebesgue measure of zero.

Comment: I used to think that Lebesgue measure is intuitive, since it is translation invariance and has $m([0,1]) = 1$. That $\mathbb Q$ has measure zero is just a consequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Potential Answer

### Definition of Measure

Consider $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ where $A\subseteq[a,b]$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $S\subseteq A$. Here $S$ is a fixed subset of $A$

Suppose we define a Lebesgue Probability Measure $\lambda_{A}(S)$ depending on a fixed set $A$ and $S$. The length of the intervals $I$ and $J$ are given by $\ell(I)=\ell(J)=b-a$. If $\left(I_{k,\epsilon}\right)_{k=1}^{m}$ are subsets of $I$ covering $S$ and $\left(J_{k,\epsilon}\right)_{k=1}^{n}$ are subsets $J$ covering $A$, if $\lambda^{*}$ is the Lebesgue Outer Measure, then the Lebesgue Outer Probability Measure is:

$
\lambda^{*}_{A}(S)=
\inf\left\{\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\ell(I_{k,\epsilon})
\bigl[1{-}\mu(A)(1{-}\mu(S\cap I_{k,\epsilon}))\bigr]\text{sign}(|A|)}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\ell(J_{k,\epsilon})
\bigl[1{-}\mu(A)(1{-}\mu(A\cap J_{k,\epsilon}))\bigr]}: S\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{m} I_{k,\epsilon}, A\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n} J_{k,\epsilon}, \left|\lambda^{*}(S)-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\ell(I_{k,\epsilon})\right|\le \epsilon, \left|\lambda^{*}(A)-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\ell(J_{k,\epsilon})\right|\le \epsilon, 1\le m \le \max\left\{|S|,1\right\}, 1 \le n \le \max\left\{|A|,1\right\}; P = S\cap I_{k,\epsilon},\\ P= A\cap J_{k,\epsilon} \ \text{or} \ P= A; \mu(P)=\inf\left\{\text{sign}\left(\bigcup\limits_{s=1}^{t}G_s\right): P\subseteq \bigcup\limits_{s=1}^{t} G_s\right\}, 1 \le t \le \max\left\{|P|,1\right\} \right\}$

Where $\text{sign}(0)=0$, when $S$ and $A$ are uncountable $|S|=+\infty$ and $|A|=+\infty$, $\lim\limits_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m} \ell(I_k)\to\lambda(S)$, $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \ell(J_k) \rightarrow \lambda(A)$ and in most cases $\epsilon$ should approach zero. Moreover, $\mu(P)=0$ when $P$ is countable and $\mu(P)=1$ when $P$ is uncountable.

Finally

> $\ell(I_{k,\epsilon})=c$ for all $k\in \{1,...,m\}$,
> $\ell(J_{k,\epsilon})=c$ for all $k\in \{1,...,n\}$, and $c\in
>  \mathbb{R}^{+}$

If $\lambda_{A}(S)\neq(\lambda(S)/(b-a))$, we could split $I_{k,\epsilon}$ and $J_{k,\epsilon}$ into two cases.

> Case 1) When $\lambda(A)>0$, $\ell(I_{k,\epsilon})=c_k$ for all
> $k\in\left\{1,...,m\right\}$ and $\ell(J_{k,\epsilon})=d_k$ for all
> $k\in\left\{1,...,m\right\}$ where $c_k,d_k \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$.
>
> Case 2) If $\lambda(A)=0$, $\ell(I_{k,\epsilon})=c$ for
> $k\in\left\{1,...,m\right\}$ and $\ell(J_{k,\epsilon})= c$ for all
> $k\in\left\{1,...,n\right\}$ where $c\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$.

From these restrictions, Inner Generalized Lebesgue Measure $\lambda_{A*}(S)$ is

\begin{equation}
\lambda_{A*}(S)=\lambda_{A}^{*}(A)-\lambda_{A}^{*}(A\setminus S)
\end{equation}

And when the limit of the inner and outer measure equal eachother

\begin{align} 
\lambda_{A}^{*}(S)=\lambda_{A*}(S) =\lambda_{A}(S)
\end{align}

Where $\lambda_{A}(S)$ is the Full Lebesgue Probability Measure.

### Properties of the Measure

It seems the properties of my measure are:

\begin{equation}
    \lambda_{\emptyset}(\emptyset)=0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \lambda_{A}(\emptyset)=0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\lambda_{A}(A)=1
\end{equation}

If $A=A_1\cup A_2$ and both subsets of $A$ are disjoint.

\begin{equation}
    \lambda_{A}(A_1\cup A_2)=\lambda_{A}(A_1)+\lambda_{A}(A_2)
\end{equation}

If $A=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}(A_i)$ then

\begin{equation}
    \lambda_{A}\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda_{A}(A_i)
\end{equation}

If $A_1=A\setminus A_2$

\begin{equation}
    \lambda_{A}(A_1)=\lambda_{A}(A)-\lambda_{A}(A_2)=1-\lambda_{A}(A_2)
\end{equation}

And if $A=[a,b]$

\begin{equation}
    \lambda_{A}(A)(b-a)=\lambda(A)
\end{equation}

I am not sure how to prove these properties are true. I'd appreciate if someone could help.

### Average and Integral

From this, we can start defining the average $f$. We start by defining $f$ as a linear combination of characteristics functions.

\begin{equation}
    1_A = \begin{cases}
   1 & x \in A  \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

We define the sum as:

\begin{equation}
\int 1_A d\lambda_{A} = \lambda_{A}(A)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \int f(c_i) 1_{A_i} d\lambda = \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(c_i) \times \lambda_{A}(A_i)
\end{equation}

Where $c_i \in [x_{i-1}, x_{i}]$ and $A_i=A\cap[x_{i-1},x_i]$ such that $a= x_0 \le \dots \le x_n =b$. Note as $n\to\infty$ we get our generalized average.

To get the "integral" multiply $S_n$ by $b-a$ and set $n\to\infty$. My hunch is the "integral" will not give the area under the curve (where we can use the anti-derivatives of $f$) unless $A$ is dense in $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 6):

There is no unique intuitive average of $P$ over an arbitrary countable subset $A$. This is for two reasons. First, viewing $A$ as just an abstract set of points to be averaged over is problematic. Any way to define an average over $A$ would have to use a specific ordering of the elements of $A$, and thus no unique or intuitive average could be achieved. You thus want to use the fact that $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (after all, why did you decide you wanted $A$ to be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and not just an abstract infinite set!). So we want to use some of the structure of $\mathbb{R}$; note that the Lebesgue average does this -- it uses intervals as the building blocks for the Lebesgue measure. Second, and related to the first, is that $P$ is an arbitrary function. If $P$ is an arbitrary function, then it doesn't care about the structure of $\mathbb{R}$; $A$ very well might then be an abstract infinite set on which $P$ is defined, and then there is no way to use that $A$ is a subset of the structured set $\mathbb{R}$. We therefore want to put some restrictions on $P$. One natural one is that $P$ is continuous.

With this context and these assumptions in mind, I'll try to provide a satisfactory answer to your (refined) question. We can assume $A \subseteq [a,b]$, since that's where everything is happening. For ease, I'll have $[a,b] = [0,1]$. Based on the above discussion, I'll just have $P$ be defined on all of $[0,1]$ and continuous. Let $E_1 = [0,1], E_2 = [0,\frac{1}{2}], E_3 = [\frac{1}{2},1], E_4 = [0,\frac{1}{4}], E_5 = [\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}], E_6 = [\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}]$, $E_7 = [\frac{3}{4},1], E_8 = [0,\frac{1}{8}]$, etc.

If $A$ is finite, it's obvious how to define the average of $P$ (just do $\frac{1}{|A|}\sum_{x \in A} P(x)$). So, assume $A$ is infinite. Consider the sets $A\cap E_1, A\cap E_2, \dots$. Let $x_1$ be a point in the first nonempty one of these sets. Let $x_2$ be a point in the second nonempty of these sets, etc. Look at the measures $\delta_{x_1}, \frac{\delta_{x_1}+\delta_{x_2}}{2}, \dots, \frac{\delta_{x_1}+\dots+\delta_{x_N}}{N},\dots$. Since $[0,1]$ is a compact metric space, there is some probability measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ that is a weak* limit of some subsequence of these measures, i.e. there is some $(N_k)_k$ with $\frac{1}{N_k}\sum_{j=1}^{N_k} f(x_j) \to \int_0^1 f d\mu$ for each $f \in C([0,1])$.

We then define the average of $P$ over $A$ to be $\int_0^1 Pd\mu$.

Benefits of this definition: (1) It coincides with the Lebesgue measure when $A = \mathbb{Q}$; in fact, it coincides with the Lebesgue measure whenever $A$ is dense in $[0,1]$. (2) It is localized to the right places (e.g. $A \subseteq [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ implies $\mu$ lives on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$). (3) It is intuitively an average; we are sampling "randomly" from the interval $[0,1]$  and taking a limit of these empirical averages of samples.

Cons of this definition: (1) It is not unique (for two reasons: (a) the choice of the $x_i$'s is not unique; (b) there might be multiple weak* limits). However, I don't think this can be avoided -- I don't think one can get a unique, intuitive average over an arbitrary countably infinite set.

My [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2352715/366088) to your question from 2 years ago (!) might be useful (good you're still studying this stuff).

I'll end with an interesting example. Consider $A = \{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5},\dots\}$. We can have, for example, $x_1 = \frac{1}{3},x_2 = 1, x_3 = \frac{1}{5},x_4 = \frac{1}{2},\dots$. Note, for fun, that each element of $A$ will eventually be included in $(x_n)_n$ (to see this, note that any number $\frac{1}{l}$ is the only element of $A$ in an interval of the form $[\frac{m}{2^k},\frac{m+1}{2^k}]$ if $k$ is large enough). In any event, the measure $\mu$ obtained will just be $\delta_0$, the delta mass at $0$, so that $\int Pd\mu = P(0)$ is just the value of $P$ at $0$. This is intuitive, since the elements of $A$ are nearly all near $0$.

.

Added: Let $P: \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be $P(x) = x^2$. Let $\tilde{P}: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be $\tilde{P}(x) = x^21_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$, and let $T: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be $T(x) = x^2$. The Lebesgue integral of $\tilde{P}$ over $[0,1]$ is $0$, and the Lebesgue integral of $T$ over $[0,1]$ is $\frac{1}{3}$. It doesn't really make sense to say "the Lebesgue integral over $\mathbb{Q}$", but, for example, what one would mean when one says "the Lebesgue integral of $x^2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $0$" is "the Lebesgue integral of $\tilde{P}$ over $[0,1]$ is $0$". The interval $[0,1]$ has the Lebesgue measure on it, so we can integrate functions over it. Since $\tilde{P}(x) = 0$ for almost every $x \in [0,1]$, it makes sense that the integral of $\tilde{P}$ is $0$. The Lebesgue integral is intuitive.

What you want, though, is to define a measure $\mu$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, so that "the average of $P$ over $\mathbb{Q}$" is simply $\int Pd\mu$. You want something different than the Lebesgue measure over $[0,1]$. (Note there is some confusing terminology here. The integral $\int Pd\mu$ is still called a "Lebesgue integral" even though the measure we are integrating over is not the Lebesgue measure). The way I defined that measure $\mu$ is described above. If $A = \mathbb{Q}$, or $\mathbb{Q}\cup \{\frac{\ln(m+\sqrt{3})}{100} : m \in \mathbb{N}\}$, or just any dense set, then what $\int Pd\mu$ turns out to be is $\int_{[0,1]} T dx$, the Lebesgue/Riemann integral of $T$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure, where $T$ is the continuous extension of $P$ to $[0,1]$. In particular, if $P = x^2$ and $A = \mathbb{Q}$, the "average of $P$ over $A$" given by my answer $\int Pd\mu$ is $\int_0^1 x^2dx = \frac{1}{3}$, the intuitive answer you sought.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98215/discussion-on-answer-by-mathworker21-most-intuitive-average-of-p-for-all-x).

Comment: @mathworker21 One more test. If $P(x)=x^2$ for $x\in[0,1/3]$, $P(x)=\sqrt{x}$ for $x\in[1/3,2/3]\cap\mathbb{Q}$, and $P(x)=3$ for $x\in[1/3,1]\cap\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, what is the average?

Comment: @Arbuja Wait, when you say $P(x) = 3$ for $x \in [1/3,1]\cap \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, is that $1/3$ supposed to be a $2/3$? I assumed it was in my above comment.

Comment: @mathworker21 It's supposed to be $1/3$. I wanted to see what happend if we intersected the rationals with the irrationals.

Comment: @mathworker21 But seeing your answer, I'm completely sure this is perfect.

Comment: @Arbuja That's a good question. My average isn't unique, for the reasons described in my answer. And I think the example of intersecting rationals with irrationals is a big reason why we can't hope for uniqueness, since they are both dense. If you want to get uniqueness, you'd have to incorporate both measure theoretic and topological considerations about your set $A$. And these two can conflict with one another in certain situations.

Comment: @mathworker21 Are you a professor. If not do you know any professors that can answer my question? Perhaps they have a better solution.

Comment: @Arbuja I've spent a long time on my answer and replying to all of your comments. I'd appreciate if you accepted my answer.

Comment: Sorry if it seemed I insulted you and sorry for my carelessness confusion. I'm kind of depressed.....I hoped there was more to explore.

Comment: @Arbuja There is more to explore! There are tons of more questions to ask and different, more specific, setups (of $A$ and $P$) to think about; all I was saying is that, at this point, I think I have adequately answered the question you posed. I am happy to have helped out and clarified your confusion. You have asked great questions!

Comment: @mathworker21 Does my answer give any more ideas? I know arbitrary countably infinite sets do not need structure but how else can we represent them? If sets do have a structure, I'm considering using specific Folner Sequences using intuition? Does this make sense?

Comment: @mathworker21 , what if you made your integral like a darboux integral?

Comment: @ZacharyHunter I don't see how my whole "weak$*$ limit of measures thing would work"

Comment: @Arbuja I still have to read it.

Comment: @mathwork21 If you downvoted my answer what’s is unclear about it?

Comment: @Arbuja I didn't downvote. I've been busy; I'll try to read it later.

Comment: @mathworker21 I know you’re extremely busy but when will you have time to check my answer?

Comment: @Arbuja I'll try to get to it soon. Are you sure it's easy to read. Scrolling through it, the notation looks non-standard.

Comment: @mathworker21 I'm not sure how else to describe it. I could do years of rigorous reading but this would take forever.

Comment: @mathworker21 How can we incorporated [Density](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3380022/how-to-rigorously-define-a-translation-invariant-measure-that-follows-these-requ) Rock answer this question.

Comment: @mathworker21 I think I proved you wrong. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3683714/analyzing-a-definition-of-average-which-uses-a-variation-of-the-lebesgue-integra).

Comment: @mathworker21 See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3709974/125918). A unique intuitive average can be determined.

Comment: @mathworker21 I haven't given up. I know I'm right. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3725235/125918). A uniquely intuitive average can be determined.

Answer (score 2):

The essence of this question moreso seems to be how to intuitively integrate on a countably infinite set. So, before we get into integrating with respect to some probability functions, lets see if we can integrate with respect to $f(x)=x$.In it's purest form, an integral is a bit like a fancy average, so let's try and think what behaviors we would want:

Let's say we have a set $A = \{C, 0,0,0,0 \dots \}$. Then treating it like a psuedo-[Cesaro-sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation), if we make $a_0=C$, we get:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^n a_i = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}(C+ \sum_1^n 0) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{C}{n} = 0$$
This works out quite nicely. Generally, it should make sense that any finite number of points  should not impact the average of $A$. This is a bit analogous to how in Lesbegue integration, any countably infinite amount of points doesn’t effect the integral. Explicitly:

**Property 1:** $\forall S= \{C_1,C_2,C_3\dots C_k\}, average(A)=average(A \setminus S)$
 However, psuedo-Cesaro-sums aren’t perfect. Consider the set $A = \{0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1 \dots\}$ where $0$ and $1$ occur infinite times. There are many ways we can order $a_i$ such that both $0$ and $1$ appear infinite times, that still different results:

$$ 0+1+0+1 \dots = \frac{1}{2} $$
$$ 0+0+1+0+0+1 \dots = \frac{1}{3} $$
$$ 0+0+0+1+0+0+0+1 \dots = \frac{1}{4} $$
$$ 0+0+0+1+1+0+0+0+1+1 \dots = \frac{2}{5} $$

In fact, you can end up with any average in $[0,1]$ being your average. In fact, this is tangentially similar to the [Riemann Series Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem), which is about how you can rearrange the terms certain kinds of sums to get different values. So, how do we handle this? If we tried to take the “average” of psuedo-Cesaro-sums, that doesn’t really help, the whole reason we’re in this mess is because averaging with infinities is hard. Despite this being an adhoc proposal, let’s assert:

**Property 2:** if you have a finite set $S = \{a,b,c\dots z \}$, and $A$ has countably infinite copies of each element of $S$, $average(A) = average(S) = \sum_{x \in S} x/|S|$

I realize with some clever model of infinite permutations you could possibly rigorously prove that the average of a psuedo-Cesaro-sum for all permutations of $A$ will be this, but that sounds rather messy and I hope we can all intuitively accept property 2.

However, we are not done, in fact, here is where things get really iffy. Consider the sets $A_1 = \{0,.9,1.1,0,.99,1.01,0,.999,1.001\dots\}$ and $A_2 = \{0,.9,0,.99,0,.999\}$. For this I suggest the analysis concept of “limit points”. $x$ is a limit point of a set $A$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists y \in A \textrm{ s.t. } |x-y| < \epsilon$. We will say $x$ is a dense limit point of $A$ if $\forall S \subset A$ where $S$ is a finite set, $x$ is a limit point of $A \setminus S$.  Now, let $x$ be dense limit point of $A$, and $y_0, y_1 \dots$ be a sequence of $y \in A$ s.t. $|x-y_i| < \epsilon_i$ with $\epsilon_0 > \epsilon_1 > \epsilon_2 \dots$ being a sequence with approaches zero. If we took the psuedo-Cesaro-sum with $a_i = y_i$, we would get that it approaches $x$, and it would stay that way even if we permitted the sequence, which also occurs if $a_i = x$ and we take the psuedo-Cesaro-sum.  So, going out on a limb, let’s do the following:

Let $D(A) := \{x|\forall S \subset A,∀  \epsilon > 0, ∃y \in A \setminus S \textrm{ s.t. } |x-y| < \epsilon \}$, for finite sets $S$. If $A$ is a countably infinite set, let $average(A) = average(D(A))$. This satisfies properties 1 & 2.
 Now, if $D(A)$ is a finite set, we can rely on the elementary average where we sum all elements and divide by $|S|$. If $D(A)$ has non-zero measure, then we can simply get the average by integrating over $A$, and divide by it’s measure. Finally, we have the case where $D(A)$ is also countably infinite, where we recursively say $average(D(A)) = average(D(D(A))$. I don’t believe that you can have infinite countably infinite $D(A)$, but lack a proof for this. Neveretheless, let’s just classify $A$ with that property as being pathological, and out of our ability to average.

With these rules in line, we can average any non-pathological countably infinite set $A$ bounded by some interval $[a,b]$. By this is I mostly meant okay that we will not go from a countably infinite set $D_n(A)$ to an empty set $D_{n+1}(A)$, which occurs if $A = \mathbb{Z}$. As a rough proof of this, we can chop $[a,b]$ in half, and we get two shorter intervals, one of which still has countably infinite points. We can repeatedly halve all our intervals, and still one will have infinitely many points. As these intervals get smaller and smaller, we end up creating at least one dense limit point. Since it’s not pathalogical, eventually $D_n(A)$ will not be countably infinite, and it won’t immediately be empty too, thus it must be finite or have non-zero measure, allowing us to average it.

So, tada! I present a method of averaging countably infinite sets which intuitively makes sense (at least to me). Now what? What about probabilities and integrals? Typically integrals are done in respect to measure, they have scale and what not. However, countable sets lack this, so I think an averages are more akin to what actually works. So, with that in mine, let us define our “integral” off of this. First, let’s say:

$$ \int_{A} x = average(A) = \frac{\sum_{x \in D_n(A)} x}{|D_n(A)|} \textrm{ if } D_n(A) \textrm{ is finite or } \frac{\int_{D_n(A)} x dx}{\int_{D_n(A)} 1 dx} \textrm{ if } D_n(A) \textrm{ has nonzero measure}$$

Then, we can extend this for general $f$ like so:
 $$ \int_{A} f(x) = \frac{\sum_{x \in D_n(A)} f(x)}{|D_n(A)|} \textrm{ if } D_n(A) \textrm{ is finite or } \frac{\int_{D_n(A)} f(x) dx}{\int_{D_n(A)} 1 dx} \textrm{ if } D_n(A) \textrm{ has nonzero measure}$$

For continuous $f$, this should be consistent with psuedo-Cesaro-sums on dense limit points. So, this would be really interesting if the justification of property 2 is consistent with “random” psuedo-Cesaro-sums. Thus concludes integration. From there, hopefully we’re just a hop and a skip away from incorporating probabilities. Yet unfortunately, my attention has been drained writing this, and lack the energy to decipher what precise model of probability you desire to implement. Perhaps you can take it from here, basing things off of Bayesian priors, or convolutions. If you are confused, or have further thoughts and ideas, just let me know, and I’ll be excited to offer some more effort into this.

Comment: for clarification: by psuedo-Cesaro-sum I mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^n a_i$

Comment: Thanks! I am hoping to create a measure that matches the results of your sum when $A\cap[a,b]$ is countable; and matches the results of the Lebesgue Integral when the Lebesgue measure of $A\cap[a,b]$ is 1. However if $A\cap[a,b]$ is uncountable and it’s Lebesgue measure is less than $1$, it can be divided into countable or null sub-intervals with the largest possible lengths, where we apply your sum, and uncountable sub-intervals where we apply the Lebesgue Integral.

Comment: yes, and by definition of this "integral", we revert to the Lebesgue integral when $A$, or I guess, $A  \cap [a,b]$, has non-zero measure.

Comment: Also, does your intuition match my intuition? For example if $P(x)$ is defined for $x\in A\cap [0,1]$, where $A=\left\{(\sqrt{m})/(\sqrt{4n+2}): m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$ and $P(x)$ equals $x$ for $A_1=\left\{(\sqrt{2m+1})/(\sqrt{4n+2})\right\}$ and equals $1$ for $A_2=\left\{(\sqrt{2m+1})/(\sqrt{2n+1})\right\}$, then what is the average using your sum? (You don’t have to show the steps.) I get something like $\frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{1} x \ + \frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{1} 1= 2/3$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97754/discussion-between-zachary-hunter-and-arbuja).

Comment: If they are both dense on $[0,1]$, then I'd say their average is $\frac{\frac{\int_0^1 x dx}{1}+\frac{\int_0^1 1 dx}{1}}{2} = \frac{3}{4}$

Comment: My intuition states if $A_1=\left\{\frac{\sqrt{2m+1}}{\sqrt{12n+6}}:m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$, $A_2=\left\{\frac{\sqrt{2m+1}}{\sqrt{2n+1}}:m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$ and $A=A_1 \cup A_2$, then $A_1$ has a "measure" of $2/3$ and $A_2$ has a "measure" of $1/3$. This is because when $x\in A_1$ is reduced it can only be written as $\left\{\frac{\sqrt{2m+1}}{\sqrt{4n+2}}:m,n\in\mathbb{Z}, \gcd{(\sqrt{2m+1},\sqrt{4n+2})}=1\right\}$ and $A_2$ can only be written as $\left\{\frac{\sqrt{4m+2}}{\sqrt{4n+2}}:\gcd(\sqrt{4n+2},\sqrt{4n+2})=2\right\}$....................................

Comment: ........................Since the "denominators" of the functions in both sets are the same, we can apply something "similar to asymptotic density" on their numerators such that $d(A_1)=\frac{\left\{2m+1\right\}\cap\left(\left\{2m+1\right\}\cup\left\{4n+2\right\} \right)\cap[0,v]}{\left(\left\{2m+1\right\}\cup\left\{4n+2\right\} \right)\cap[0,v]}=2/3$ and $d(A_1)=\frac{\left\{4m+2\right\}\cap\left(\left\{2m+1\right\}\cup\left\{4n+2\right\} \right)\cap[0,v]}{\left(\left\{2m+1\right\}\cup\left\{4n+2\right\} \right)\cap[0,v]}=1/3$

Comment: Currently I'm defining "measure" of $A$ as the measure of $D(A)$. If you can formalize your intuition of measure, then the getting the averages to work would be an easy extension. But from what I have seen you have not sufficiently defined measure. Could you try to formally list the properties you seek to capture with this "measure"?

Comment: I don't know how to? I could wait years to master the concepts but I wanted to know if I am on the right track.

Comment: I think mathworker21 solved the question? There is no unique intuitive average but there are special cases.

Comment: Mine will give you a unique average which is well defined.

Comment: might I ask what’s wrong with what I have now? my results match lebesgue measure when A is dense, matches mathworker21’s intuition in his last example, and it is always unique and well defined .

Comment: @ZacharyHunter my answer is unique when $D(D(\dots D(A)))$ eventually terminates, and my answer is defined when it doesn't. Also, what if $D(A)$ is countably infinite but measure $0$? How does your answer work then?

Comment: If $D(A)$ is countable infinite then we look $D(D(A))$, but I admitted that I have nothing concrete if that doesn’t terminate. I assume we’d take a limit of $D(\dots D(A)\dots )$. However, are we sure this can occur in a finite segment? because $D(D(A)) \subsetneq D(A)$ if $D(A)$ is finite.

Comment: @ZacharyHunter I think looking at $D(D(A))$ if $D(A)$ is countably infinite is not intuitive. For example, take $A$ with $D(A) = \{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\dots\}\cup\{0\}$ (e.g. $A$ consists of $\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\dots\}\cup\{0\}$ together with exponentially small countably infinite sets around each $\frac{1}{k}$, with $\frac{1}{k}$ being the only limit point in that exponentially small countably infinite set around $\frac{1}{k}$). Then your average would only output $P(0)$, since $D(D(A)) = \{0\}$. However, I think we really should be

Comment: averaging over all the points $\frac{1]{k}$ and $0$, since $A$ genuinely contains those points.

Comment: No I actually like that feature, and intentionally chose to reflect that, because to my intuition zero is infinitely more dense than other points

Comment: also, does the average of that sum reach zero in the limit?

Comment: @ZacharyHunter If $P(x)=x^2$ for $x\in[0,1/3]$, $P(x)=\sqrt{x}$ for $x\in[1/3,2/3]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ and $P(x)=3$ for $x\in[1/3,1]\cap\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, what is the average?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{r}$ is dense, it’s measure is greater than both other sets, thus it would be 3

Comment: @ZacharyHunter Intuitively over $[0,1]$, the average of $P$ should be $\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{1} x^2 dx + \frac{2}{3}\int_{0}^{1} 3 dx= 19/9$.

Comment: Countable set have zero measure so they matter infinitely less in the average than anything with measure, such as ℝ

Comment: @ZacharyHunter Does my answer give any ideas? Does any of it make sense?

Comment: No it doesn’t really make sense how countable sets effect the average when there are sets with measure, you just get inconsistencies at this point

Comment: @ZacharyHunter I meant my answer to my original post. I was thinking about using Folner Sequences.

Comment: @ZacharyHunter Did you read my answer to my post. I was thinking about using Folner Sequences. What do you think? Does it make sense?

Comment: @ZacharyHunter Ok I guess it makes no sense.

Comment: @ZacharyHunter See the [new answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3709974/125918) to my question. Everything should make sense this time.

Comment: @ZacharyHunter I've made more progress. If I'm not correct I'm one step closer. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3725235/125918).